# Package names for domains which end in .do

Tags: java, android, google-play, package

Convention when building an app holds that the package name should begin with one's reverse domain string, e.g., com.google.MySampleApp.

However, our company is registered at a .do domain, which cannot be used as a package name (!) because "do" is a reserved keyword in Java.

How do people usually handle this?  Is there an "official" standard for the Google Play Store in particular?  Surely we can't be the first company with a domain in the Dominican Republic that's created an Android app...?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Oracle suggests you add an underscore:

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package
>   name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other
>   special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other
>   character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or
>   if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int".
>   In this event, the suggested convention is to add an underscore. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> hyphenated-name.example.org   org.example.hyphenated_name
> example.int                   int_.example
> 123name.example.com           com.example._123name
> ```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: Thank you!  I was convinced there had to be some "standard" solution.